# Good Style for using zip() to iterate over tuple with 4+ items

Tags: python

For a pre-processing workflow I need to perform an identical workflow (collect data from .csv, files, clean, aggregate etc.) for multiple quantities (temperature, relative humidity etc.). For this I use a for-loop to iterate over tuples containing meta-information about the individual quantities. These statements tend to grow rather large. Is there a cleaner more elegant way to achieve this ?

I already thought about initiating the tuples beforehand and iterate over a list of tuples, but IMHO this doesn't really make the code more readable.

```py
    for quantity, inputFileName, aggregationMethod, locationShapeFile in zip([temperature, relativeHumidity, wind, radiation, precipitation],
['temp.csv', 'rh.csv', 'wind.csv', 'rad.csv', 'prec.csv'],
['mean', 'mean', 'mean', 'mean', 'sum'],
['locTemp.shp', 'locRH.shp', 'locWind.shp', 'locRad.shp', 'locPrec.shp']):
    collect(quantity, inputFileName, aggregationMethod)     
    aggregate(aggregationMethod, locationShapeFile)
```

Comment: assign variables above the for loop instead? Its not entirely clear what you're asking for

Comment: assign variables above loop as in: tempTuple = (temperature, 'temp.csv', 'mean', 'locTemp.shp') and iterate over these tuples?

Comment: No, `input_files`, `aggregations` and then `perhaps_i_should_be_an_object_list_in_the_first_place = zip(input_files,aggregations...` and iterate over that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as already suggested by @Sayse in comments - define variables before the loop

```
quantities = [temperature, relativeHumidity, wind, radiation, precipitation]
csv_files = ['temp.csv', 'rh.csv', 'wind.csv', 'rad.csv', 'prec.csv']
methods = ['mean', 'mean', 'mean', 'mean', 'sum']
shp_files = ['locTemp.shp', 'locRH.shp', 'locWind.shp', 'locRad.shp', 'locPrec.shp']
for quantity, csv_file, method, shp_file in zip(quantities, csv_files, methods, shp_files):
    collect(quantity, csv_file, method)     
    aggregate(method, shp_file)
```

also you may shorten it

```
data_points = ['Temp', 'RH', 'Wind', 'Rad', 'Prec'] # maybe there is better name than data_points?
quantities = [temperature, relativeHumidity, wind, radiation, precipitation]
methods = ['mean', 'mean', 'mean', 'mean', 'sum']
for dp, quantity, method in zip(data_points, quantities, methods):
    collect(quantity, f'{dp.lower()}.csv', method)     
    aggregate(method, f'loc{dp}.shp')
```

- f-strings require python 3.6+

Answer (score 0):

Using zip for this already leads to quite compact code; note that you can reduce number of characters by 23% by using shorter variable names, eg:

```
for q, inp, agg, loc in zip(
    [temperature, relativeHumidity, wind, radiation, precipitation],
    ['temp.csv', 'rh.csv', 'wind.csv', 'rad.csv', 'prec.csv'],
    ['mean', 'mean', 'mean', 'mean', 'sum'],
    ['locTemp.shp', 'locRH.shp', 'locWind.shp', 'locRad.shp', 'locPrec.shp']):

    collect(q, inp, agg)     
    aggregate(agg, loc)
```

An alternative is to use [numpy.vectorize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) which is designed for such application of function over parallel iterables:

```
import numpy as np

def f(q, inp, agg, loc):
    collect(q, inp, agg)     
    aggregate(agg, loc)

np.vectorize(f)(
    [temperature, relativeHumidity, wind, radiation, precipitation],
    ['temp.csv', 'rh.csv', 'wind.csv', 'rad.csv', 'prec.csv'],
    ['mean', 'mean', 'mean', 'mean', 'sum'],
    ['locTemp.shp', 'locRH.shp', 'locWind.shp', 'locRad.shp', 'locPrec.shp'])
```

Comment: I'm aware of np.vectorize, but I don't think this makes the code more readable.

Comment: yes agree, though it is subjective :) 74% of the code characters is contained in your 4 lists so no matter what you use on top, they still cluster your field of vision. Using the zip with previously-declared lists is likely the best option. Also, you could merge collect and aggregate into one function